# Without passing search term how to do query using sosl

Tags: sosl

I have run this sosl Query in editor,It gives zero records

```
 FIND {Doc*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Document__c ( Revision__c,name,Release_Date__c,Part__c,Part__r.name,PartValueSOSL__c,PlatformSOSL__c,Release_Date_value__c,AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c,Content_Document_Ids__c,RecordType.Name WHERE AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c = 'Airbus'  and  recordtype.id in ( '012m00000008oqCAAQ','012m00000008r6MAAQ','012m00000008opnAAA','012m00000008oq7AAA','012m00000008scdAAA','012m00000008oq2AAA','012m00000008opsAAA','012m00000008opxAAA','012m00000008r6HAAQ')  )
```

By testing purpose I just ran same query using "soql":

```
   select Revision__c,name,Release_Date__c,Part__c,Part__r.name,PartValueSOSL__c,PlatformSOSL__c,Release_Date_value__c,AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c,Content_Document_Ids__c,RecordType.Name WHERE AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c = 'Airbus'  and  recordtype.id in ( '012m00000008oqCAAQ','012m00000008r6MAAQ','012m00000008opnAAA','012m00000008oq7AAA','012m00000008scdAAA','012m00000008oq2AAA','012m00000008opsAAA','012m00000008opxAAA','012m00000008r6HAAQ')  )
```

Above soql query gives 4 records.

Here DOC * represents search text.

my question is: Why soql and sosl gives different result in case

What changes I have to make for search text to get "4 records"

I have tried like this

```
    Doc-*, *doc*
```

seems like I dont have any field with "doc". So i have decide to change the sosl query without using search text. Is it possible? or any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOSL searches based on the search term. Here `doc` will be your search text and it is not the field name on which it will be searching.

> Use SOSL when you don’t know which object or field the data resides in, and you want to:

- Retrieve data for a specific term that you know exists within a field. Because SOSL can tokenize multiple terms within a field and build a search index from this, SOSL searches are faster and can return more relevant results.
- Retrieve multiple objects and fields efficiently where the objects might or might not be related to one another.
- Retrieve data for a particular division in an organization using the divisions feature.

I prefer using SOSL, when I need to search in LongTextArea or RichTextArea where SOQL query doesn't support those in `WHERE` clause for filtering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77303/discussion-between-santanu-boral-and-annappa-ph).